# Нужен метод,который убирает подряд все пробелы и оставлять лишь 1 пробел

Tags: c#

Как сделать функцию, которая бы убирала все пробелы, идущие подряд в какой-либо строке, оставляя только 1 пробел

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+", " ");
```

Comment: Стрельба из пушки по воробьям.

Comment: @Bulson, ну так напиши нормальный вариант, который не из пушки. Только который нормально пробелы между словами чистит, а не бесполезный trim.

Answer (score 6):

Ответ @Qwertiy правильный, но добавим немного экзотики для разнообразия:

```
string.Join(" ", inputText.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

Comment: Интересный вариант.

Answer (score -2):

```
string str = "     lala   ";
str = " " + str.Trim(); //будет " lala"
```

Comment: А если пробелы в середине? `"la     la"` PS: кстати, парсер их съедает, оставляя лишь один.

Comment: Ваше замечание противоречит изначальному условию задачи. Так можно нафантазировать, что пробелы имеются между буквами.

Comment: @Bulson в условии же не сказано, что пробелы могут быть только в начале или в конце строки.